# Error al guardar datos de una clase en Phyton 3 para almacenar en una DB en SQLite3

Tags: python-3.x, base-de-datos, sqlite3

estoy empezando con Phyton 3 y SQLite3. Tengo una clase Pelicula que hereda de la clase Categoria. Luego de instanciar el objeto para almacenarlo en una DB de SQLite3, me da un error de "***ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type***".
Intenté cambiando lo que me devuelve el objeto, sin resultados. Necesito una orientación o ejemplo de como puedo resolver el inconveniente. Muchas gracias.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3


class Categoria(object):
    def __init__(self, categoria):
        self.categoria = categoria

    def __str__(self):
        return ('%s : %s' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.categoria))


class Pelicula(Categoria):
    def __init__(self, categoria, titulo, sinopsis, fecha, director):
        Categoria.__init__(self, categoria)
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.sinopsis = sinopsis
        self.fecha = fecha
        self.director = director

    def __str__(self):
        return ('{\'Título\' : \'%s\', \'Categoria\' : \'%s\', \'Sinopsis\' : \'%s\', \'Fecha\' : \'%s\', \'Director\' : \'%s\'}' % (self.titulo, self.categoria, self.sinopsis, self.fecha, self.director))


tituloPelicula = input('Título película: ')
categoriaPelicula = input('Género película: ')
sinopsisPelicula = input('Sinopsis de la película: ')
fechaPelicula = input('Año de producción: ')
directorPelicula = input('Director: ')
pelicula = Pelicula(categoriaPelicula, tituloPelicula, sinopsisPelicula, fechaPelicula, directorPelicula)
print(pelicula)
conexion = sqlite3.connect('videoteca.db')
sql = "INSERT INTO peliculas(titulo, categoria, sinopsis, fecha, director) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cur = conexion.cursor()
cur.execute(sql, pelicula)
conexion.commit()
```

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al método `cur.execute()` le tienes que pasar como segundo parámetro una tupla (al menos con la sintaxis que estás usando en la que usas interrogantes como *placeholders* para los parámetros). Lo que le pasas en cambio es un objeto python de la clase `Pelicula`.

Deberías extraer los atributos `titulo`, `categoria`, `sinopsis`, etc. del objeto y crear una tupla. Sería así:

```
cur.execute(sql, (
   pelicula.titulo, 
   pelicula.categoria, 
   pelicula.sinopsis, 
   pelicula.fecha, 
   pelicula.director))
```

Pero hay problemas adicionales de diseño en tu código.

El primero es lo de heredar de `Categoria`. ¿Por qué? No se gana nada con ello excepto complejidad. Puedes hacer simplemente que la `Pelicula` tenga un campo `categoria`, igual a sus restantes campos `titulo`, `director`, etc. y simplemente hacer `self.categoria = categoria` desde su `Pelicula.__init__()`.

Me pregunto el por qué tomaste esa decisión, e imagino que es porque en la base de datos quieres tener una tabla de categorías separada de la tabla de películas, para no repetir categorías innecesariamente. En ese caso nada de lo anterior funcionará, pues necesitarías crear relaciones entre tablas (claves foráneas, etc) y usarlas en las consultas, y la herencia no te ayuda en esto. Por otro lado, por la misma razón deberías tener una tabla de directores, y por tanto una clase `Director`, etc. El diseño se complica. La solución más simple sería que la categoría fuese simplemente una cadena más, como el título o la sinopsis. Esto, claro, te llevará a una base de datos no normalizada, pero tú decides si te merece la pena normalizarla.

### Otra vía

Una alternativa a implementar tú mismo todo esto, es hacer uso de un ORM, que es una biblioteca que se ocupa de realizar las conversiones entre tu modelo de datos (las clases Python) y las tablas y consultas de la base de datos. Puedes usar por ejemplo [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee) que es muy simple, o [PonyORM](https://ponyorm.org/) que prácticamente oculta todo el SQL subyacente exponiendo una API muy pythónica (además éste tiene un editor gráfico online en el que puede crear tu modelo de datos, tablas y relaciones, y te genera el código python que lo implementaría). Luego está el todopoderoso y venerable [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), más complejo y potente, pero creo que quizás excesivo para tu caso.

El inconveniente de usar un ORM es que tus clases `Categoria` y `Pelicula` tienes que crearlas ya de una forma muy específica, siguiendo las especificaciones del ORM que vayas a usar, para que éste sepa cómo realizar las conversiones hacia y desde la base de datos. La ventaja es que esas conversiones serán automáticas, así como las relaciones entre tablas, operaciones JOIN, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, esa era la duda. No me daba cuenta de cómo extraer la tupla. Y consideraba la forma de pasar equivocada. También estuve leyendo ORM y me interesó bastante. Voy a agarrar práctica y empezar a implementarlo.  Gracias por el aporte.